# Qt C++ and QSerialDevice: Windows 7 USB->Serial Port Reading/Writing

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am attempting to read from/write to an RS-232 capable device. This works without issue on Linux. The device is connected via a Digitus USB/Serial Adapter.

The device shows up in Device Manager as COM4.

```
void PayLife::run() {
    this->sendingData = 0;
    this->running = true;
    qDebug() << "Starting PayLife Thread";
    this->port = new AbstractSerial();
    this->port->setDeviceName(this->addy);
    QByteArray ba;
    if (port->open(AbstractSerial::ReadWrite| AbstractSerial::Unbuffered)) {
        if (!port->setBaudRate(AbstractSerial::BaudRate19200)) {
            qDebug() << "Set baud rate " <<  AbstractSerial::BaudRate19200 << " error.";
            goto end_thread;
        };

        if (!port->setDataBits(AbstractSerial::DataBits7)) {
            qDebug() << "Set data bits " <<  AbstractSerial::DataBits7 << " error.";
            goto end_thread;
        }

        if (!port->setParity(AbstractSerial::ParityEven)) {
            qDebug() << "Set parity " <<  AbstractSerial::ParityEven << " error.";
            goto end_thread;
        }

        if (!port->setStopBits(AbstractSerial::StopBits1)) {
            qDebug() << "Set stop bits " <<  AbstractSerial::StopBits1 << " error.";
            goto end_thread;
        }

        if (!port->setFlowControl(AbstractSerial::FlowControlOff)) {
            qDebug() << "Set flow " <<  AbstractSerial::FlowControlOff << " error.";
            goto end_thread;
        }
        while(this->running) {
            if ((port->bytesAvailable() > 0) ||  port->waitForReadyRead(900)) {
                ba.clear();
                ba = port->read(1024);
                qDebug() << "Readed is : " << ba.size() << " bytes";
            }
            else {
                qDebug() << "Timeout read data in time : " << QTime::currentTime();
            }
        }
    }
    end_thread:
    this->running = false;
}
```

On Linux, I don't use QSerialDevice, just regular serial reading/writing.

No matter what, I always get:

```
Starting PayLife Thread 
Readed is :  0  bytes 
Timeout read data in time :  QTime("16:27:43") 
Timeout read data in time :  QTime("16:27:44") 
Timeout read data in time :  QTime("16:27:45") 
Timeout read data in time :  QTime("16:27:46")
```

I am not exactly sure why.

Note, I tried first to use regular Windows API reading and writing with the same results, i.e. it just doesn't ready any data from the device.

I am 100% sure that there is always something to read from the device, as it spams ENQ across the connection.

Comment: As an update: Using SerialMonitor, the device can be opened, and works as expected. So this isn't a windows thing, but somehow has to do with how I am using QSerialDevice

Answer (score 1):

You should generate the doxygen documentation of `QSerialDevice` if you haven't already done so. The problem seems to be explained there.

On Windows in unbuffered mode:

> Necessary to avoid the values of `CharIntervalTimeout` and
>   `TotalReadConstantTimeout` equal to 0. In theory, it was planned that at
>   zero values of timeouts method `AbstractSerial::read()` will read the
>   data which are in the buffer device driver (not to be confused with
>   the buffer `AbstractSerial`!) and return them immediately. But for
>   unknown reasons, this reading always returns 0, not depending on
>   whether or not a ready-made data in the buffer.

Because `read` waits for the data in unbuffered mode, I guess `waitForReadyReady` doesn't do anything useful in that mode.